# ENFILE: File table overflow Node.js

Tags: node.js, math, primes

I am trying to make a more memory efficient prime number generator. I can't think of anything better than using a file as my prime number array, and read line by line synchronously. I run this and at about 29000 it gives me the `ENFILE: File table overflow` error. Any ideas to fix/improve this code?

[This is the library I'm using](https://github.com/nickewing/line-reader)

```js
#!/usr/bin/env node

var num = 3,
    prime,
    fs = require("fs"),
    readline = require("./line_reader.js");

console.log("Hundreds: 2");
console.log("Hundreds: 3");

function appendPrime (num) {
  fs.appendFileSync("Primes.txt", num+'\n');
}

while (true) {
  prime = true;
  var times = Math.floor(Math.pow(num, 0.5));
  if (num % 2 == 0 || num % 3 == 0) {
    prime = false;
  } else {
    readline.eachLine("Primes.txt", function (line, last, cb) {
      if (num % line == 0) {
        prime = false;
        cb(true);
      } else {
        cb();
      }
    });
  }
  if (prime) {
    var place = String(num).length;
    switch (true) {
      case place <= 3:
        console.log("Hundreds: "+num);
      break;
      case place <= 5 :
        console.log("Thousands: "+num);
      break;
      case 6 :
        console.log("Hundred thousands: "+num);
      break;
      case place <= 8 :
        console.log("Millions: "+num);
      break;
      case 9 :
        console.log("Hundred millions: "+num);
      break;
      case place >= 10 :
        console.log("Billions or above: "+num);
      break;
    }
    appendPrime(num);
  }
  num += 2;
}
```

Comment: `readline.eachLine` is async function so you open too many files are in a loop

Comment: Disc access is slow.  A good implementation of the Sieve of Eratosthenes can be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 16384 16384 && ulimit -n 16384
```

Comment: please explain why does it answer the question?

Comment: You are getting a lot of files loaded in memory by node, and it is reaching the the limit and breaking, this code above is to increase that limit